# Contract a path (set of paths) into an edge (a set of edges) in neo 4j graph

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph with several node types (PERSON, CITATION, JOURNAL) and relationship types (authored_in, published_in, cites, referred, etc.) in my neo4j graph instance. While I like to keep the graph as is, I also want to run closeness centrality, clustering coefficients algorithms only for the graph formed by the PERSON nodes and the edges obtained by contracting the paths connecting pairs of PERSON nodes into single EDGES.

I think I can replace the original graph with a PERSON-PERSON graph - but I do not want to lose the original graph. Is there a way to store the original graph into "supernodes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a new relationship `type` to connect the existing `Person` nodes. Nothing else needs to change.

Comment: Thanks! Would I be able to zoom into the newly created  Person-Person relationship type and view the list of paths from Person - Person?  I understand that I can do all this by storing these under "Properties" of the relationship type - but I am also wondering about visualizing these Person-Person paths as edges and vice versa.

Comment: You can use a [variable-length relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/clauses/match/#varlength-rels) to get the paths. For example, `MATCH path=(:PERSON)-[:MY_TYPE*]->(:PERSON) RETURN path`.